# How to get image link on acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

I was wondering how to get the image file on my acumatica by code i want to get the image link by a button click i tried

```
InventoryItem itemnow = (InventoryItem)Base.ItemSettings.Current;

var getimgurl = itemnow.ImageUrl.ToString();
```

my current code only get the actual name of the image 2149821748912.jpg (example) and not its external link

[image]

[image]
i want to get the web link on it and not the image name on my action button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External Link is just a link to `/Frames/GetFile.ashx` and passing the `FileID` like below:

> https://test.acumatica.com/Instance/Frames/GetFile.ashx?fileID=bdb9534c-6aa9-41fa-a65d-3119e32b0fe5

For building this link you only need to get the `FileID` of the attachment. Code below is building the links for all the attachments fo the current `Inventory Item`.

```
var currentItem = this.Base.Item.Current;
List<string> links = new List<string>();
if (currentItem!=null)
{
    var fileAttachments = PXNoteAttribute.GetFileNotes(this.Base.Item.Cache, currentItem);
    foreach (Guid fileId in fileAttachments)
    {
        links.Add("SITE_URL/INSTANCE_NAME" + "/Frames/GetFile.ashx?fileID=" + fileId);
    }
}
```

Please take into consideration that the `/Frames/GetFile.ashx` requires authorization before accessing the file, you will get the sign-in form if you access it in incognito.